# Total time spent in state $i$ before reaching state $i+1$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, markov-chains, birth-death-process

Let $T_k$ be the total cumulative time spent in state $i$ before reaching state $i+1$ in a continuous time birth-death process, with birth and death rates $\lambda_k$ and $\mu_k$. What is the distribution of $T_k$?
To solve this problem, I tried to set up the equation:

$P(T_k < z) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty P(T_k< z | N_k=n)*P(N_k=n)$

But, I ran into a problem calculating both $P(N_k=n)$, which should be geometrically distributed with $p=1-\rho_{k,k}$, where $\rho_{k,k}$ is the probability of returning to state k from state k in finite time. $P(T_k< z | N_k=n)$ having a gamma distribution also seems to complicate the problem.

Comment: $\rho_{k,k}$ is really the probability to return to $k$ starting from $k$ without hitting $k+1$ first. Finite time doesn't really have anything to do with it because the event of oscillating strictly below $k+1$ forever will have zero probability.

Comment: I see. So then $\rho_{k,k}$ is really the probability that we move from $k$ to $k-1$, or $\frac{\mu_k}{\mu_k+\lambda_k}$

Comment: That is correct.